# How to write in a CSV document

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write on a CSV document. I need open one CSV document, take the row `created_at` (date and time) and break than in two rows Dia (Day) and Hora (Hour), but it's not writing.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Teste\teste.py", line 30, in <module>     
    writer.writerows(dia,hora) 
TypeError: writerows() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Code:

```
import csv 
import os

fin = open('teste.csv', 'r')  
fout = open('teste2.csv', 'w')

reader = csv.DictReader(fin, delimiter=',') writer = csv.DictWriter(fout, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)  

writer.writeheader() 

with open(os.path.join('teste2.csv'), 'wb') as csvfile:     

    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = ['dia','hora'], delimiter = ',')     
    writer.writeheader()    

for row in reader:      
    arquivo = row['created_at'].split("T")[0]      
    data = arquivo.split("T")[0]     
    dia = data.split("-")[2]      
    horario = row['created_at'].split("T")[1]     
    hora= horario.split(":")[0]     
    writer.writerows(dia,hora) 

fin.close() 
fout.close()
```

Comment: You need e.g. `writer.writerows([dia, hora])` - `writerows` takes an iterable of rows, not the individual rows themselves, as parameters.

Comment: With writer.writerows([dia, hora]) presents the message error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Teste\teste.py", line 25, in <module>
    writer.writerows([dia,hora])  
  File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 157, in writerows
    rows.append(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: '1', '9'

Comment: Then, as you're using the DictWriter, you'll have to make sure the rows you're trying to write are dictionaries with the correct keys for the field names. It actually looks like you don't want to write two *rows* at all, but rather two *fields*, in which case `.writerow({'hora': hora, 'dia': dia})`. Please try googling your error messages, it usually finds you something useful, and provide a [mcve] that explains what you're trying to do.

Comment: @MarinaOliveira Você mandou a mesma pergunta tanto na comunidade em português, quanto em inglês, pensei que aqui o pessoal iria ajudar, mas não é o que parece...